# Does PGP encrypt all messages or only that one send with PGP?

Tags: encryption, email, pgp, openpgp

If I encrypt my Email with PGP will all of my emails will be encrypted or only that ones that people send to me using my PGP key?

If I register on Facebook or Dropbox and they send me an email: "Activate your account" this email will be encrypted or not?

Answer (score 3):

PGP only encrypts the emails you send out. Secondarily, you can decrypt PGP-encrypted emails if you have the sender's key.

Facebook and Dropbox do not send PGP-encrypted emails.